# Added maven to android project

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to add https://github.com/npgall/concurrent-trees/blob/master/documentation/Downloads.md to my project in the gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        compile group: 'com.googlecode.concurrent-trees', artifactId: 'concurrent-trees', version: '2.4.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
```

This is for the specific module. I'm a little confused. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're adding it to your project's build.gradle. Try to add it to dependencies of your module's build.gradle

```
compile 'com.googlecode.concurrent-trees:concurrent-trees:2.4.0'
```

Quoting [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html)

> Android Studio configures projects to use the Maven Central Repository
>   by default. (This configuration is included in the top-level build
>   file for the project.)

and

> In most cases, you only need to edit the build files at the module
>   level.

Comment: Thank you! Is there documentation for this ?

Comment: Yes check this one: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html